# How does the memory management of weak instance variables work inside of a block when ARC is enabled in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

When referencing a weak ivar inside of a block in Objective-C when ARC is enabled, does the runtime implicitly retain the object to which the ivar belongs? For example:

```
- (void) foo {
    void (^block)() = ^{
        [_weakIvar doSomethingAwesomeButNotTooAwesome]; // Is self retained here?
    }
    block();
}
```

While we're at it, how about a weak property in the same scenario?

```
- (void) foo {
    void (^block)() = ^{
        [self.weakProperty doSomethingAwesomeReallyAwesomeDudeYeah];
    }
    block();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_weakIvar` really means `self->_weakIvar` under the hood which means that what is (automatically) retained is `self`. Same thing applies when doing `self.weakProperty`.

In your particular example, the block is not copied (and used right away) so nothing is retained at all but if you do (for example):

```c
- (void) foo {
    void (^block)() = ^{
        [_weakIvar doSomethingAwesomeButNotTooAwesome];
    }
    dispatch_async(queue, block); // here, block is copied and so self is retained
}
```

Comment: However, even if `self` is retained by the block being copied onto the heap, it doesn't necessarily create a cycle, does it?

Comment: It creates a cycle if self is retained by the block *and* the block is retained by self (such as if the block was stored in an instance variable or strong/copy property).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I wasn't sure of the implementation details of blocks. In the .NET world where I come from, "delegates" (roughly the same as blocks) have different memory management semantics.

Comment: By the way, I was aware that `_weakIvar` means `self->_weakIvar`, but since the compiler is smart enough to know that `_weakIvar` is weak, I thought it might be smart enough *not* to retain the implicit `self` unless it was referenced through `_smartIvar`, for instance.